# How to send setState to root page from last page on Navigator stack?

Tags: flutter

I design my app, and I decided use routes and use firebase for auth.

In root page there are some button if user want to login with email go to `EmailLogin` page

In `EmailLogin` page if user dont register before go to `EmailRegister` page and register.

And I use 3 time `Navigator.pop()`, pop from stack : `EmailRegister`, `EmailLogin` and `LoginPage`
And then push `LoggedIn` but when I push the back button I see black screen.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'loginPage.dart';
import 'login-register/emailLogin.dart';
import 'login-register/emailRegister.dart';
import 'login-register/authentication.dart';
import 'logged-in/logged-in.dart';


BaseAuth auth = new Auth();

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      //home: LoginPage(),
      initialRoute: '/',
      routes: {
        // When navigating to the "/" route, build the FirstScreen widget.
        '/': (context) => LoginPage(),
        '/loggedIn' : (context) => LoggedIn(auth: auth),
        '/emailLogin': (context) => EmailLogin(),
        '/emailRegister': (context) => EmailRegister(auth: auth),
        //'/emailRegister': (context) => EmailRegister(),

      },
    );
  }
}
```

I changed my idea and decide to desing `HomePage` for root route, if user is log in in user see `LoggedIn` page and  otherwise see `loginPage` but I need to send setstate to `HomePage` widget but how I send ? Because page stack look like this: root -> login -> register

I send callback every page or what I need to do ?

Answer (score 0):

I think the way you have arranged the page routes before was correct. You can use,

1. `Navigator.of(context).popUntil()`, to go back to root.
2. `Navigator.of(context).pushAndRemoveUntil()`, to push the Home and remove until root

although this might sort your navigation query, I still don't get why you want to setState() in homepage. An explanation or some code would be better

Comment: After register I need go home and in setState if user login return loggedinpage else return loginPage.

Comment: May I suggest implementing StateManagement? https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/intro

You can use a plethora of methodologies such as BLoC, Reudx as explained here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3tm-R7ymwhc